# Radio SelectOption as a list

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable, radio-button

[image]I am using the below code in my VF page to display cases with an option to select(Radiobutton):

```
<apex:selectRadio label="Select Case to Update" value="{!excase}">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!casesradio}"/> <br></br>
</apex:selectRadio>
```

Using this I get all my cases in a single row , side by side. I would like the cases to appear in a list one below another. I tried pageblockTable , but it did not work.

```
  <apex:pageblocktable value="{!excase}" var="exscases">
  <apex:column headervalue="Cases">
    <apex:selectRadio label="Select Case to Update" value="{!excase}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!casesradio}"/>
    </apex:selectRadio> <br></br>
  </apex:column>
 </apex:pageblocktable>
```

Any heads up on how can I achieve this?

Comment: See my answer in chat from your previous question

Comment: Hello I get a different view now, Can you please see the chat?

Comment: see also http://cropredysfdc.com/2014/02/20/aligning-labels-with-selectradio-within-a-pageblocksection/

Comment: @cropredy good source , I will check it out. I am figuring out how to put radio select option inside page blocktable

Comment: Check the solution for this at - [http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118313/radio-button-not-in-sync-with-each-other](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118313/radio-button-not-in-sync-with-each-other)